# typescript: how to declare types in another javascript module

Tags: typescript, module, declaration

suppose that I have a JavaScript library that export some types for uses(says js1.js). and I have some typescript codes that sits in a "<"script type="module">" tag that I want to use these type for(says ts1.ts), so I may write

import {sometype} from "./js1.js"

but in order to let the compiler know these types I need a description file(says ts1.d.ts). what should I put in this description file to make all works?

I tried to find some resource on the web and in typescript documentation but couldnt find something useful.

Comment: What is a "tag" in this context?

Answer (score 1):

1. your `blah.d.ts` MUST be named same as your `blah.js`
2. your `blah.d.ts` must be exporting the same things your `blah.js` export, but with types rather then

Alternatively you may just have `blah.ts` with the exact same code as `blah.js` but with added types, it'll work same

e.g.

```
// blah.js
export function add(a, b) { return a + b; }
// blah.d.ts
export function add(a: number; b: number): number;
```

OR

```
// blah.js
export function add(a, b) { return a + b; }
// blah.ts
export function add(a: number; b: number): number { return a + b; }
```